# AppendTo in combination with pure function

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

```
spA = {}; spB = {}; spC = {};

AppendTo[#, {"Up", "Down"}] & /@ {spA, spB, spC}
```

doesn't work in *Mathematica* 11.1.1.

Why? What is an alternative?

Comment: just plain `Append` ?

Answer (score 4):

It's an evaluation leak issue. You could try:

```
spA={}; spB={}; spC={};

Function[Null,AppendTo[#,{"Up","Down"}],HoldAll] /@ Unevaluated@{spA,spB,spC};
spA
spB
spC
```

> {{"Up", "Down"}}
>
> {{"Up", "Down"}}
>
> {{"Up", "Down"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = b = c = {};
```

Using `Append` with `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2)

```
{a, b, c} //= Map @ First @* Append[{"Up", "Down"}];

{a, b, c}
```

{{"Up", "Down"}, {"Up", "Down"}, {"Up", "Down"}}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `Insert`:

```
a = b = c = {};

Flatten@Insert[{"Up", "Down"}, #, 1] & /@ {a, b, c}

(*{{"Up", "Down"}, {"Up", "Down"}, {"Up", "Down"}}*)
```